# Choregraphe - Define local method

Tags: python, windows, nao-robot, choregraphe

Is it possible to define a local method in Choregraphe which I can use not only in the box / script editor where I defined that method and instaed using it in different boxes.

So far I created a python box with that one special method in it and everytime I used the function of the box I inserted it in my Flow Diagram. But I don't think this is the best way.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't the best way indeed.

Two possibilities:

- Include that function in a python module that you package with your application and then import from inside choregraphe - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799150/pepper-robot-upload-python-modules/45807104#45807104) for how to do that.
- Have most of your code outside Choregraphe - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929031/pepper-robot-how-to-port-python-landmark-detection-to-choregraphe/50930910#50930910) for some discussion of this approach and pros and cons vs others.